# Convert internal wiki page into PDF

Tags: pdf, wiki

My team uses internal wiki pages for all kinds of stuff. The pages are created with MediaWiki. I wonder if there is any way to convert the wiki pages into PDF format. I have to use it to convert the user documentation to PDF format, so that it can be shipped with the next release. I have seen the 'Download as PDF' option on wikipedia but our internal wiki does not have it. Is there any plugin available which would allow me to convert it?

Comment: what wiki software are you using?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Pdf_Export)?

Answer (score 2):

The Collection Extension has been decommissioned. The last long term support version supporting it will end of life in June 2019 according to 
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Version_lifecycle.

The Wikimedia foundation has stopped any development of a replacement after some failed attempts according to https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Topic:Uxkv0ib36m3i8vol&topic_showPostId=uxsjbpkqfmgq1jyx#flow-post-uxsjbpkqfmgq1jyx.

Closed source alternatives are under development by a least two companies. A working open source solution is available as a Debian package, Windows binary, and online converter http://mediawiki2latex.wmflabs.org/, which has been developed by a German worker in a cowshed using the Haskell programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia uses [the Collection extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Collection) with OfflineContentGenerator (OCG) for this purpose.